# MySQL Server 8.0.18 has failed Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL Server. I am trying to install MySQL Server 8.0.18 on Windows 10 laptop.

I am new to MySQL, so I have not tried anything other than to install.

This is the log file:

```
Beginning configuration step: Backing up MySQL database

Starting MySQL Server in order to run the mysql_upgrade tool.
Warning: There may be some errors thrown by MySQL Server, the mysql_upgrade tool is going to be run next to attempt to fix database incompatibilities.
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.18...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --port=3306 --datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data" --console...
Process for mysqld, with ID 17596, has been started successfully and is running.
Successfully started process for MySQL Server 8.0.18.
2019-10-19T19:36:28.801560Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 10152
2019-10-19T19:36:28.817090Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2019-10-19T19:36:28.817406Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-10-19T19:36:28.817691Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-10-19T19:36:28.818371Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.........................
Running mysqldump tool to backup the database...
Backup files will be dumped to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Backup\mysql_dump-2019-10-19T12.39.26.sql".

Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=root --default-auth=caching_sha2_password --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --routines --events --single-transaction=TRUE --all-databases --result-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Backup\mysql_dump-2019-10-19T12.39.26.sql"...
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect
Process for mysqldump, with ID 6468, was run successfully and exited with code 2.
Ended configuration step: Backing up MySQL database
```

I expect MySQL Server 8.0.18 should be installed. The error message is:

`The configuration step (Backing up MySQL database) is taking longer than expected. The configuration for MySQL Server 8.0.18 has failed.`

What do I need to do to get a successful install?

Thanks
-w

Comment: Do you have an older version installed?

Comment: This question has  nothing to do with sw development, this is a pure admin question. The dba sister site of SO can offer more support.

Comment: We have a discussion to that topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466225/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-when-i-just-start-to-confi?noredirect=1#comment103267345_58466225

Comment: Can you validate that C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data exist.